# Find the length of the radius of a inscribed semicircles

Tags: geometry

This is a problem that came from AoPS Online Facebook page......can anyone find the solution to it?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? If you included what you tried, it would help others help you. See [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/595055).

Comment: Start by joining P and Q to the midpoint of CD. These two line intervals equal the radius of the purple semicircle. Find it, then double it to find CD.

Comment: @Varum vajella ...I tried to solve this problem by finding the height of isoceles triangles with two given sides of 12...but as I use the formula I've been stucked on how to find height of the perlendicular bisector at line segment PQ ..can anyone give me a picture/link for the solution?

Comment: @1123581321...  thanks 

Comment: Can anyone give me the solution??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

$R$ is the center of the bigger semicircle. $S$ is the center of the smaller semicircle.

Radius $RC = 6, $ radius $CS = r$.

Then $RS^2 = 6^2 - r^2 = 36 - r^2$

$PR = 3, PT = \frac{7}{2}, RT = \frac{1}{2}$.

$ST^2 = RS^2 - RT^2 = \frac{143}{4} - r^2$

But also, $ST^2 = PS^2 - PT^2 = r^2 - \frac{49}{4}$

So, $2r^2 = \frac{192}{4} \implies r = \sqrt {24}$

$CD = 2r = 4 \sqrt6$

Comment: thankyou so much

Comment: How do you know that CS and RS are perpendicular?

Comment: @1123581321 $R$ is the center of the bigger circle and $S$ is midpoint of the chord ($CD$) of the same circle.